# Start-Job: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create groups in parallel then wait until all jobs are finished and afterwards do some permissions on the groups.

This is my code:

```
$initScriptBlock = {
function Invoke-createProjectADGroup {
    param(
        [string]$groupname,
        [string]$c_manager,
        [string]$ou,
        [string]$c_description,
        [int]$gid,
        [string]$project,
        [Object[]]$members
    )
       .....
}

$jobs = @()


$Scriptblock = {
        param(
            [string]$groupname,
            [string]$c_manager,
            [string]$ou,
            [string]$c_description,
            [int]$gid,
            [string]$project,
            [Object[]]$members
        )
        Invoke-createProjectADGroup -groupname $groupname -c_manager $c_manager -ou $ou -c_description $c_description -gid $gid -project $project -members $members
    }

$jobs += (Start-Job -InitializationScript $initScriptBlock -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $groupname_pm, $c_manager, $ou, $c_description, $group_pm_gid, $c_projectname, $c_members_pm)

....
# some more jobs
....
#wait for all jobs to be finished
Receive-Job $jobs -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Unfourtunatley I get this error message:

> PS>TerminatingError(Start-Job): "A positional parameter cannot be
> found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'."

Has somebody got an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would help to post the full error next time. Can only imagine the error is coming from `Receive-Job`, try `$jobs | Receive-Job` instead.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thanks for your answer, I updated the error message to make it more clear what the actual issue is. The Script Terminates with the first Start-Job (found that out via Transcript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a fix for the issue. Instead of telling the Scriptblock all the  params, you can just give it a list and then work with the built in $args:

```
$Scriptblock = {
    Invoke-createProjectADGroup @args
}

$jobs += (Start-Job -InitializationScript $initScriptBlock -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList @($groupname_pm, $c_manager, $ou, $c_description, $group_pm_gid, $c_projectname, $c_members_pm))
```